# EF - related entity not loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got a related entity that I use to store all my static data. Problem is, when I create a new entity, the related entity is always null.
There is no issue when pulling data from the db - I can access the related entity just fine.

Using EF 6.0, model first, if that matters.

I've tried using .Include, and also re-fetching after the save, but it's not working. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing... any help? TIA

```
...
using (var db = new dbContext1())
{            
    Customer c = new Customer();
    c.id = this.id;
    db.Customer.Add(c);
    db.SaveChanges();

    for (int i = 1; i <= c.CustomerProperties.initialAllotment; i++)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

In the Customer class:

```
public int id { get; set; }    
public virtual CustomerProperties CustomerProperties { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting `CustomerProperties` if you just add it and save changes then it will not be magically set by entity framework. You have to load those static properties from `db` and add it to your `Customer` and then save.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't instantiated an instance of the CustomerProperties class. I would imagine using this, before the `db.SaveChanges();` would fix your problem.

```
 c.CustomerProperties = new CustomerProperties();
```

Also, using `CustomerProperties` as the name of the class, and the name of the property may cause you some problems.

I would suggest using this instead:

```
 public int id { get; set; }    
 public virtual CustomerProperties customerProperties { get; set; }
```

Note the change from [Pascal Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to [Camel Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for the property's name.

See: [Property Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzcth91k%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)